# Export-State produces wrong collators hex

Tags: chainspec

I am experimenting with the export state command. For now I am testing it on my local machine. So, for this purpose, I spin up polkadot relay chain with two validators and connect one collator of my parachain with it. I am using my custom key to be used as sudo and collator/session keys.

Afer executing export-state command, I restart my parachain collator using the newly generated chain-spec and registered it with the relaychain too (using the new genesis and wasm files).

I observed that the collator hex address of my parachian has changed. I checked it using chainstate → auraExt → authorities. I wonder why is  the collator hex changed and how to add my actual collator?

I am attaching the collator hex before and after executing the export-state command.

Here is the collator hex address before export-state:
[image]

Here is the collator hex after export-state:
[image]

Comment: Is the block you are querying the data at (before export) the same one you are actually exporting the state from ?

Comment: In case you are using collator-selection pallet I would be curious to see what values you have for invulnerables and desiredCandidates

Comment: 1. I query the block before exeucting export-state.  2. I am not using selection pallet

Comment: Should I raise this question again?

Comment: Then, what's the value of this key at the same block the one you exported the data from ?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. That shows collator adress before export-state and after export-state