# Does export-state produces a random collator address?

Tags: chainspec

While running export-state command against my parachain, I observed that the resultant raw parachain specs has a diffirent collator address as compared to the original one.

Does the export-sate changes the collator keys and generate some random key for the collator? If yes, how can I get my original collator(s) back in the raw chain specs?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a different key but rather the encoding of your collator address in the storage for that respective pallet. If you're looking at the (key,value) map in the exported state, it will contain the encoded (key,value) which is possibly the hash of the actual data you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Drew for the quick answer. So, do you mean it is the hex of the actual address. More ever, should we need to change some thing in the collator address so that to make it the original collator address

Comment: If you can please have a look on another of my related question, you may get more insight of what I wanted to ask. I will thankful, if  you can help me on that. 

https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8103/export-state-produces-wrong-collators-hex?noredirect=1#comment8185_8103

Comment: Any one can please help me on this?